# Can't add zeros after decimal (.) in Calculator in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I was creating a Calculator app using React and when I added decimal functionality , I found a bug that I was not be able to add zeros after decimal (.).

```
const value = e.target.value;

setCalc({
 ...Calc,
 num: !Calc.num.toString().includes(".") ? Calc.num + value : Calc.num,
});

}
```

Is there a way that I can add zeros after decimal ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You are trying to add zero along with the decimal if the `num` field in the object does not contain decimal value. If yes, You have to add dot `(.)` as well while concatenating.

Demo **:**

```js
const value = 0;
const Calc = {
  num: 999
};

console.log(!Calc.num.toString().includes(".") ? Calc.num + '.' + value : Calc.num);
```